# DockLeft custom size

Tags: c#, .net, dockpanel-suite

I am trying to set DocContent DockLeft to custom size but it is not working. Can anyone suggest how to accomplish this?
I was testing this code but it ends up with default width 404 not 700 as I set.

```
dockPanelMain.SuspendLayout(true);
DockContent myContent = new MenuForm();
myContent.ShowHint = WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DockState.DockLeft;
myContent.Show(dockPanelMain);
dockPanelMain.DockWindows[WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DockState.DockLeft].Width = 700;
dockPanelMain.ResumeLayout(true, true);
```

Comment: I haven't figured this out either.

Answer (score 13):

**DockLeftPortion**
Size of the left docking window. Value < 1 to specify the size in portion;
value > 1 to specify the size in pixels.